# can't find element by id or xpath in appium 1.15.1

Tags: java, android, appium

I use appium **1.13.0** and there is element i can inspect by id and xpath but when upgrade appium to **1.15.1** the same element doesn't have id or xpath and i cant inspect it what is the reason for that???

Comment: Share your page/app with us

Comment: Please add the app XML or hierarchy